# How to render a EJS view and use a Controller inside a route?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

How to render a EJS view  and use a Controller inside a route?
 Im trying render a view and using a controller to create a user (mongodb) inside a route, but my controller's being called before the view rendering
what to do?

routes.js

```
routes.get('/', UserController.createuser,(req,res) => {    
    res.render('home')
})
```

---

UserController.js

```
async createuser(req,res) {           
        const user= await User.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            surname: req.body.surname
        })
        return res.send("Success")            
    }     
routes.get('/', UsuarioController.cadastrar,(req,res) => {    
    res.render('home')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to render view inside controller.

routes.js

```
routes.get('/', UserController.createuser)
```

in  UserController.js

```
async createuser(req,res) {

    const user= await User.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        surname: req.body.surname
    })
   res.render('home' , {user})
}
```

Comment: Hi. Its working, but now i cant send the datas to database because im not using routes.post :(

Comment: you can use post method and save data into database in createuser controller

Comment: how?   are you saying to use Get on routes.js and post inside the controller? 
im confused, sorry

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: docker with mongodb

Comment: you have to look into mongodb insertOne or mongoose save function (if you are using mongoose)